# android I want action bar like this

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to make action bar like this..

[image]

please help me to do like this I try to like this but i can not got it please help me with complete tutorials .I am new in android.
this is `Activity` code

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: use AppCompat and give your material design colors in style. thats it.

Comment: Actionbar or status bar?

Comment: You want Toolbar with action button and status bar, is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

### see [this link also](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

See this Demo on [github](https://github.com/NileshJarad/android-mvp-material-and-realm)

From that use `toolbar` layout and copy `styles.xml`

> Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MyTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- customize the color palette -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

> toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: sorry i cant understand it please help me to understand it

Comment: see the demo you will get idea